# extend 2 classes problem android

Tags: java, android

i'm a junior programmer. I have a base class that extends activity, i use this class to set up the menu in my app. All my activity classes extends this base class. Now, i have a new class which extend ExpandableListActivity this class's purpose is to show an expandable list and of course when the user is viewing this activity the menu becomes unavailable. So how can i do to be able to use the menu while viewing the expandable list. I know that it's impossible to extend more than one class in Java, so what's the trick?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use **delegation**. Extract all methods related to Menu in separate MenuDelegate class.

Your new class will extend ExpandableListActivity, and delegate all methods related with Menu to MenuDelegate. It's useful solution if your Menu logic is simple.
In this case, your other activities will be free, and will be able to extend ListActivity, TabActivity or something else..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: I'm trying to do as you say. But i get an error here is what i did after the onCreate method in expandable list activity: **Categories.java** ´@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.appmenu, menu);
     return true;
 }
   
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    BaseActivity b = new BaseActivity();
    
    b.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }´

Comment: no, no, no... BaseActivity b = new BaseActivity(); b.onOptionsItemSelected(item) ... it is very wrong - to create Activity manually.

Comment: First you should make MenuDelegate class with constructor MenuDelegate(Activity activity){this.activity = activity;} and methods createMenu(Menu menu){MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); inflater.inflate(R.menu.appmenu, menu); return true;}, selectMenuItem(MenuItem item){switch(item.getItemId()){case R.id.new_game:...; return true; case R.id.quit:activity.finish();return true;...}

Comment: Second, in your ExpandableListActivity you can use this delegate like this onCreate(Bundle bundle){this.menuDelegate=new MenuDelegate(this);}, onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){return menuDelegate.createMenu(menu);}, onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){menuDelegate.selectMenuItem(item);}. It is trick, it will work. Depending of your situation it may be useful, but may be hard code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to extend ExpandableListActivity to have an ExpandableList in your layout. You can extend your BaseActivity and handle the ExpandableList on your own. The ExpandableListActivity is just a helper class.